# Determining number of threads for sending mails using smtp

Tags: spring, multithreading, performance, architecture, jakarta-mail

I have to send 500 mails per user in an hour using Java mail api (SMTP).
To accomplish that i have created a schedular which runs every hour gets all the users and allocate each user a thread to send mails.And i have created a fixed Thread pool of 10 threads so at a time 10 users is proccessed,But it takes around 10 minutes to process it.

Ex: 1 thread per user 500 mails.
    For 10 users 10 threads 5000 mails.

How do i send mails to 10k users, since 10 users are proccessed at a time.
What will be the ideal number of threads to accomplish the above task within the time limit of 1 hour.

System Specs : RAM 4GB.
HD : 500GB

My app is build on SpringBoot.

Thanks.

Comment: One question - which comes to mind is - if you have a connection limit with your SMTP server and/or a rate limit. In our company we don't send emails on our own with SMTP, but we just push it to external email providers like Mandril per REST API and they take care of sending them to the users.

Comment: We are not using any third party services,we are sending mails on user's behalf by taking their permission for send mails. Yes mail providers have their own limit but we are handling it.